# Java - HTML parser (and obtaining JavaScript binding events)

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to parse a HTML document (from a URL), and obtain, mainly, the events binded to its elements by JavaScript.

The question is, is there any API/Util in Java to render an entire HTML docuemnt with JavaScript, and access the result like in a browser?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are many. They can be obtained via a google search. Here is my favorite: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html